# Run a sql query that deletes a column before a date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am running SQL Server 2008 R2. I want to run a query that will delete data in column `referralSource` before a specific `referralDate` in the `dbo.Referral` table.

Here is a screenshot of what I am talking about:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: this is a really basic sql task... you should consider making a few tutorials before continuing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
update dbo.Referral 
set referralSource = null 
where referralDate < some_specific_date
```

For `some_specific_date` you can put e.g.
`'20101201'` or any other value you need.